# How does one get row data from a Silverlight DataGrid?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid

In Silverlight, how does one get row data from a DataGrid that is full of data?

I have gotten this far (in a method that receives a button click on a row(:

```
DataGridRow item = (DataGridRow)dg.SelectedItem;
```

Now, how do I get the individual components of the item that I guess is the selected row?

Help me out here. How do you bind an observablecollection to the grid?

How do you use the cast system when you cast to the object?

When I read the data into the grid, I used this class:

```
public class Data
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool Available { get; set; }
    public int index_1 { get; set; }
    public int index_2 { get; set; }
    public int index_3 { get; set; }
    public int index_4 { get; set; }
    public int index_5 { get; set; }
    public int index_6 { get; set; }
    public int index_7 { get; set; }
    public int index_8 { get; set; }
    public int index_9 { get; set; }
    public int index_10 { get; set; }
    public int index_11 { get; set; }
    public int index_12 { get; set; }
    public int index_13 { get; set; }
    public int index_14 { get; set; }
    public int index_15 { get; set; }
}
```

So how so I cast when I read back out

This does not work:

```
Data _mydata = new Data();  
YValue = (_mydata.index_1)dg.SelectedItem;
```

This does not work:

```
YValue = (index_1)dg.SelectedItem;
```

This does not work:

```
YValue = (Data().index_1)dg.SelectedItem;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have bound a `ObservableCollection<Foo>` to your grid, your selected item can just be cast into your object - `(Foo)dg.SelectedItem`

EDIT-- UPDATE TO ANSWER UPDATED QUESTION

The simple answer is, if you are not using MVVM (which I assume by your post your not), in the code behind create a collection (preferably ObservableCollection) of Data and set the grids itemsource property to your collection

```
public ObservableCollection<Data> MyCollection{get;set;}

void SetGridItemsSource()
{
// populate your collection here, then use the below line to associate it with your
// grids itemssource      
MyGrid.ItemsSource = MyCollection;

}

public void GetSelectedItem()
{
   //Simply cast the selected item to your type
   Data selectedItem = (Data)MyGrid.SelectedItem;
}
```

Comment: Help me out here.  How do you bind an observablecollection to the grid?  How do you use the (Foo) when you cast to the object?  When I read the data into the grid, I used this class:                                                                        public class Data
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public bool Available { get; set; }
        public int index_1 { get; set; }
        public int index_2 { get; set; }
   }

Comment: @xarzu, hope my upated answer helps

Answer (score 2):

```
DataGridRow item = (DataGridRow)dg.SelectedItem;
int index1 = ((Data)item).index_1;
```

That will give you the value of the first index.

Comment: It gives me an exception. But when I cast to my custom object it works. Anyway I would like to get DataGridRow.